# GWT MultiWordSuggestOracle: How To Search Via Backend

Tags: gwt

I have a question regarding the GWT MultiWordSuggestOracle ...

According to the examples I've seen, in order to populate the oracle with data, you need to load the data in the frontend:

```
private MultiWordSuggestOracle oracleProducts = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
oracleProducts.clear();
for (ProductDTO product : products) {
    oracleProducts.add(product.getDescription());
}
....
productTextBox = new WatermarkedTextBox();
new SuggestBox(oracleProducts, productTextBox)
```

As soon as you have 10 of these text fields with autocomplete on your page, and each of them is filled with 100+ strings, things get a little slow, especially on slower internet connections.

Is there an alternative to the oracle / suggestbox which doesn't requires prepopulating the autocomplete field with data or which sends a request to the backend to do the searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement `SuggestOracle.requestSuggestions` and do your RPC/RequestFactory/REST call to your backend there.

This is how we implemented a contact suggestbox by doing a REST call to the backend :

```
@Override
public void requestSuggestions(final Request request, final Callback callback) {
    SearchCriteria criteria = new SearchCriteria(request.getQuery());
    criteria.setPageSize(request.getLimit());
    RestClientFactory.getContactClient().search(criteria,
            new Result<SearchResult<Contact>>() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SearchResult<Contact> result) {
                    Response resp = new Response();
                    resp.setMoreSuggestions(!result.isLastPage());
                    resp.setSuggestions(ContactMultiWordSuggestion.fromContacts(result.getList()));
                    callback.onSuggestionsReady(request, resp);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to make the backend do the searching, loading everything into the frontend just didn't feel right.

Answer (score 1):

You're free to implement `SuggestOracle` the way you want.

The now-deprecated GWT-Incubator project has an [example using RPC](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/client/RPCSuggestOracle.java) which you can easily copy and adapt.

Answer (score 0):

try to use setLimit()  for SuggestBox instance this should do the work

Comment: It would still require me to load all the strings into oracleProduct.
I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to preload anything, where the "search request" is sent to the backend which handles the search. Not sure if that will slow down the oracle's search capabilities.